# Java. Перехват Http

Tags: java

У меня задача написать автотест на java, который при вызове php кода из докер контейнера проверит, что пошел http запрос на подгрузку данных в гугл аналитику.. Все примеры моков которые я встречал требуют четкого адреса , который нужно заменить. А я не знаю такого четкого адреса, потому что он формируется динамически кучей запросов в php коде. И я хочу просто проверять , что при вызове php файла происходит http request все равно куда.

Comment: Из вопроса непонятно с помощью чего/где/откуда необходимо перехватывать запросы: из Java-приложения в коде или просто на локальной машине используя сниффер? Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте в него больше информации для чёткого понимания вопроса/задачи/проблемы.

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: Так откуда выполняется запрос: из PHP в Docker'e или из Java?

Comment: Цепочка такая. Я запускаю несколько контейнеров. Один из них - апачи сервер с php кодом. Другой - контейнер с java тестами. ИЗ которого  я запускаю созданный мной динамически в тестах файл в апачи контейнере. он вызывает файл artisan и тот с помощью кэрнела выполняет подгрузку данных на гугл аналитику. Я хочу из джава тестов перехватить этот запрос не зная его url

Comment: Все что я хочу - чтобы мой код перехватывал ВСЕ http запросы

Comment: Скорее всего Вам нужен сниффер. [В этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26152931/3129992) обсуждается похожая задача и способы её решения.